# How to enable internet on ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server

I am beginner and tried to up own ubuntu server and get stuck with no internet on ubuntu server.
I plugged in it ethernet but no internet

Comment: and everything is worked fine

Comment: Good. If you still have a question, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question to contain it. If the issue has resolved itself, you can delete your own question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `ip -a` and remember interface name
2. `ip link set dev interface-name up`
3. `dhclient interface-name`

and everything worked fine